# How do I get Docker host mode networking to work on a Pi?

Tags: raspbian, networking, docker

I have Docker running on my Pi running Raspbian right now, so far it's okay but I want to enable [host mode networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) so that I can obtain the source IP addresses of requests going to my container.  At present I can only use overlay network but when I enable host mode networking by uncommenting the lines in my compose file

```yaml
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
#        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
#        mode: host
```

performing a `netstat -ant | grep LISTEN | grep :80` does not show any results.

Comment: A couple of questions if you don't mind: Are you using `dhcpcd` as your DHCP client & network manager? Have you modified `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` with the `static <value>` option?   Maybe `grep -E 'LISTEN|ESTABLISHED'`?

Comment: I used whatever the default one is for DHCPD I don't recall setting anything of the sort.

Second is there's still no result for port 80 or 443 (to the server)

Comment: If you've been through the [host tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/)? Have you got the correct network driver? - is it an `arm` version (if you installed all of this through `apt` I'm sure it's OK).

Comment: Your comment actually led me to the fact it's a configuration error

Comment: Good for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add another network that only traefik had access to (even if it is `overlay`).

Now I get the source IP correctly in the access logs and Traefik forwards it is X-Forwarded-For and X-Real-IP to the services.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  edge:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --global.checknewversion=false
      - --global.sendanonymoususage=false
      - --accesslog
      - --ping
      - --certificatesResolvers.default.acme.tlsChallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.email=support@trajano.net
      - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/default.json
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=https
      - --entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.http.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.https.http.tls.certresolver=default
      - --entrypoints.https.http.tls.options=default
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://daemon:2375
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
    volumes:
      - letsencrypt:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - outside
      - traefik
      - daemon
    healthcheck:
      test: traefik healthcheck --ping
    deploy:
      mode: global
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1.0'
          memory: 256M
    image: tecnativa/docker-socket-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - daemon
    environment:
      NETWORKS: 1
      SERVICES: 1
      TASKS: 1
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 32M
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    networks:
      - traefik
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 64M
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Path(`/whoami`)
        - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entryPoints=https
        - traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80
networks:
  daemon:
    internal: true
    attachable: false
  outside: # I NEEDED THIS
    driver: overlay
  traefik:
    name: traefik
    internal: true
    attachable: true
volumes:
  letsencrypt:
```